# Just Can't Remember The Actual Puzzle

Tags: riddle

Something I should've seen before but forgot.

```
N  A          NN 
 DT          E  B
 EM          S  S
S  E          DI
```

Comment: XO = Hug & a Kiss? :-/

Comment: @Techidiot, Hey tech. Hugs and kisses to you too!

Comment: Liking your current rep (2048 if it changes) ;)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - Good eye! As of now, it still is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think

> You were asking us to get a couple of expressions out of this block.
>
> ```
>  N N N A
>  E D T B
>  S E M S
>  S D I E
> ```
>
> And you just remember the answer which is a hug and kiss(XO) part of the above structure.
>
>  Also the block says **Absent Mindedness** reading rightmost top corner going down.

Comment: I will accept this answer Tech. There's more to it, but this will work for now. Good job.

Comment: @John Where's my bounty? :-) Nice job to you too!

Comment: I don't think you need any more points. You seem to be doing just fine. :)